# gcloud auth application-default print-access-token not finding my environment variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on following the steps for Google Cloud Text to Speech via curl as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio-text-command-line).

I have a Service Account with its key in google-credentials.json (this currently works for Google Cloud Storage).

in Terminal I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable two different ways:

1. While within the application working directory, I set it to:

   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="google-credentials.json"

or

2. Setting the absolute path

   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="~/Projects/dbsan2/google-credentials.json"

Performaning

```
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

returns the given value I set it to.

Running nano $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS only opens the file for the first approach, the second opens a blank document.

running the following command as described in the article above:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d @request.json \
    "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize"

WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 1 of 3. Reason: timed out
WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 2 of 3. Reason: timed out
WARNING: Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable on attempt 3 of 3. Reason: [Errno 64] Host is down
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.print-access-token) Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a service account key file. It's a security bad practice. **AND EVEN IF IT'S MENTIONED IN THE GOOGLE CLOUD DOCUMENTATION** (and I'm fighting against that and Google for years now!!)

Indeed, the Jordi answer works, but you have to know why.

In the CURL command

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d @request.json \
    "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize"
```

You don't use the service account, you use the current logged user. Apparently your current user is not authenticated.

You can perform a `gcloud auth application-default login` to authenticate yourselves. You can also use the alternative to impersonate a service account (if you prefer using the service account roles/permissions) `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=<service account email>`

---

However this solution could not work with your curl. Indeed, a user is not linked to a specific project, (as a service account is).

There is a solution to fix that, without using a service account key file. You have to add an additional header [`x-goog-user-project`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgooguserproject), to obtain that

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -H "x-goog-user-project: <Your Project ID with Text to Speech API activated>" \
    -d @request.json \
    "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize"
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to the use of double quotation marks. I would set it like this:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/Projects/dbsan2/google-credentials.json
```

Also make sure that you are setting it as a system wide env variable and not a limited user session one.

Comment: This worked like a charm, literally.  How do I ensure the env is set system wide instead of limited to just this shell session?

Comment: Guillaume explained deeper on the process when running a CURL. To answer your question `export` is the command to go to when you want to set up an env variable. What you were doing before is just assigning a user wide variable.